# Easiest Way to Poll A Web Server

Tags: python

I have a job that I want to run a specific time each day. The job should look at a web server to see if a file exists. If it exists, I want to download the file and do something with it. If it doesn't, then I want to wait a minute and then try again.

At the moment I just have a `try-except` statement that catches the exception if the file doesn't exist and then sleeps, and passes the file back to the calling function if it does. The works okay, but I feel like it's a rather cumbersome solution.

Is there an accepted, or even just more Pythonic, way to achieve this? There are no asynchronous or threading considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import sleep

while True:
    r = requests.get("http://www.domain.com/fileYouAreMonitoring.bin")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # we got the file!
        # exit or wait until next day, use break to escape while loop
    else:
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: may I suggest making this a cron job instead of making a script wait a whole day

Comment: It is a cron job. It's also wrapped in some logic that will raise an error if the file hasn't been uploaded within a certain amount of time from the time it's meant to be uploaded. It was just his one piece of functionality that was irritating me.